# How to i refer the method from two difference interface

Tags: c#

How can refer the method definition for the interfaces which are providing same method and i want to define that function in a class.
For example I have two interfaces

```
 public interface i1
{
    void show();

}

public interface i2
{
    void show();
}
```

Suppose a class ClassA implement these interface. Will they conflict in definition or how should i define it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one case, when conflict is possible - when you need to have several methods in one class with same signature (method name and parameters are same). Usually you can just rename one method to solve this conflict. But when you implement interfaces, you can't change signature of implemented methods. If several interfaces have method with same signature AND you need different implementations of that methods, then use [explicit interfaces implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to solve conflict:

```
public class A : i1, i2
{
   void i1.show() { ... }
   void i2.show() { ... }
}
```

Usage:

```
A a = new A();
i1 x = (i1)a;
x.show(); // will call i1.show() implementation
```

As @ryadavilli stated, you need explicit implementation only if you need different implementations for different interfaces. Otherwise one `show()` method will satisfy both interfaces. If there is only one method, then there is no conflicts.

*BTW* in C# we use PascalCase for methods naming.

Comment: Which method can i access from class A if show method have different implementation. How it is handled then?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this

```
class A : i1, i2
{
    void i1.show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1");
    }

    void i2.show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("2");
    }
}
```

If you jsut want to have a single implementation for both show()

```
class A : i1, i2
{
    public void show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("common method.");
    }
}
```